Is it okay to drill through beams perpendicular to joists?
I had a buddy install some recessed lighting and noticed that he drilled through a piece of wood perpendicular to the joists. Is this allowable? Is it potentially a load-bearing beam? It does not run the length of the room, only a portion of it and it has a few pieces of wood stacked on top of one another.  The hole is 1/2" and the total height of all the beams is one foot.


that is permitted

Having your buddy do electrical work on your house probably isn't permitted. Is he a licensed electrician?

I agree with Jasen that it's not a concern structurally. However, you haven't given us enough information to know whether it's load-bearing or not. To answer the question you posed, yes, it's potentially load bearing.

I'm not sure what I'm looking at there, but there is a lot of wood. and it looks like the wood at the bottom is supporting the wood at the top.
Given that, such a small hole in the upper joist even if it may be  a little close to the edge is not going to cause any problem.
